# Net Beans Drag and Drop Function Not Working

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

A friend of mine is trying to learn java programming on Netbeans, and the drag and drop function does not work on the program. He is unable to drag files into the program.

He is on a Mac OS X, version 10.11. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: That has nothing to do with NetBeans but everything with how your friend wrote the Java program.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have much exposure in NetBean as i am using Eclipse, but your problem looks like you try to add component in container which is not supported for  particular component, try to add component in container or layout manager which is supported by them.